# PowerShell parse XML do not work for single entry

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I created a script to parse all the server names from a XML file. It works fine when there are more than 1 entry.

Somehow the script do not work when there is only one entry in the XML.

Here is the XML:

```xml
<Env>
<Web>
    <sr id="Server001"></sr>
    <sr id="Server002"></sr>
    <sr id="Server003"></sr>
</Web>
</Env>
```

Here is the PowerShell script:

```bsh
# Load servers list 
$pth =  "C:\Support\Auto\Config_xml\TEST.xml"
[xml]$css = Get-Content $pth
#
Write-Host "Preparing servers list...."
$sra = @()
for ($i=0; $i -le $css.Env.Web.sr.Length -1; $i++) {
    $svn = $css.Env.Web.sr[$i].id
    $sra += $svn
}
$sra
```

Would anyone advise what is the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug such an issue like shown in the code below in ISE or VSCode. Note how I dumped the type to see what's going on.

```
x1
Object[]
x2
XmlElement
```

Also, using `foreach` handles arrays and single objects...

```
$x1 = [xml]@'
<Env>
<Web>
    <sr id="Server001"></sr>
    <sr id="Server002"></sr>
    <sr id="Server003"></sr>
</Web>
</Env>
'@

"x1"
$x1.Env.Web.sr.GetType().Name

$x2 = [xml]@'
<Env>
<Web>
    <sr id="Server004"></sr>
</Web>
</Env>
'@

"x2"
$x2.Env.Web.sr.GetType().Name

"foreach1"
foreach($item in $x1.Env.Web.sr)
{
    "ID is $($item.id)"
}

"foreach2"
foreach($item in $x2.Env.Web.sr)
{
    "ID is $($item.id)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work when there is only one `<sr>` node because in that case `$css.Env.Web.sr` does not return an array. The returned node doesn't have a `Length` (or `Count`) property, so your `for` loop is simply skipped over.

That's why it's practically always preferable to use `SelectNodes()` (or `SelectSingleNode()`) with XPath expressions.

```
$sra = $css.SelectNodes('//sr') | Select-Object -Expand id
```

Add the array subexpression operator if you need `$sra` to be an array regardless of the number of `<sr>` nodes:

```
$sra = @($css.SelectNodes('//sr') | Select-Object -Expand id)
```

Comment: HI Ansgar, thanks for your advise. It is working fine now.